# name 'Str' is not defined: Why it shows an error about definition of the variable?

Tags: python

[image]

Hello, I have entered the code below:

```
def guessnumber():
    Str = eval(random.randint(1,101))
y=eval(input("guess a number:"))
```

but I got an error here when the code executes: Str is not defined:

```
if(y<Str):
    print("your guess is low")
elif y<Str:
    print("your guess is high")
else:
    print("Congratulations,you win!")
```

[image]

Comment: You're never calling the function `guessnumber`. Also, you need to return the str from the function and then assign it to a variable outside

Comment: Why are you calling `eval` in `eval(random.randint(1,101))`?

Comment: Are you suer you use `eval` the way you think ? I'm not sure you need it

Comment: It's also confusing to call your variable `Str` when it's actually an integer. Instead of calling `eval` twice, you'd be better with `Str = str(random.randint(1,101))` and just using `y = input("guess a number:")`; this would also be safer

Comment: @roganjosh  i have done your instructions but i receive still the same error.

Comment: You need to go with the suggestion that @sshashank124 gave; you've not called your function and you need to assign the return to a name in the local scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables assigned inside a Python function are local - accessible only within that function. To actually define a global (ie. accessible everywhere) variable from within a function, use the `global` keyword:

```
def guessnumber():
    global Str
    Str = random.randint(1,101)
```

Also, you don't have to `eval` a `random.randint`. It already returns a number, attempting to `eval` it results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    eval(random.randint(1,101))
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

Comment: @Nima_Eb You are calling `guessnumber(Str)` but your guessnumber function does not take any arguments. Try `guessnumber()` instead.